# Отправка клавиши в неактивное (свернутое окно) C#

Tags: c#, c++

Помогите с реализацией отправки клавиши в неактивное (свернутое окно) программы. Заранее уже известны hWnd и ProcessID. SendMessage не работает. Так же рассматриваю варианты на C++